# How do I do a "needs" on a nested controller for emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router:

```
this.resource('foo', {path: '/foo'}, function() {
    this.resource('foo.bar', {path: '/bar'}, function() {
        this.route('wat', {path: '/wat'});
    });
});
```

My `FooBarWatController` is a singleton and I need access to the `FooBarController`'s model. What does the `needs` look like for `FooBarWatController` to have access to the `FooBarController`?

```
FooBarWatContoller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['?'],
    action: {
        something: function() {
            console.log(this.get('controllers.?.model').get('id'));
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FooBarWatContoller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['foo/bar'],
    action: {
        something: function() {
            console.log(this.get('controllers.foo/bar.model').get('id'));
        }
    }
});
```